# How to validate a number with format *** *** ****?

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery and i am trying to validate a cell phone number or home number with the format ### ### ####. # being a place holder for a digit.

At the moment i am using number but that gives problems with spaces, and i'm using minlength 10 because all SA numbers are min 10 digits.

My code already looks as follows:

```
// Validation of Form
function validateForm() {
    $('#frmMain').validate({
        rules: { 
                 TelNumber: { required: true, number: true, minlength: 10 }
                },
        messages: {
                TelNumber: { required: 'Tel number Required' }
               },

        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $('#btnSubmit').click();

        }
    });
}
```

Here i found a add on for a US Phone number, if some one could tel me how a US phone number looks maby i can just edit this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneUS", function(phone_number, element) {
    phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, ""); 
    return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
        phone_number.match(/^(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/);
}, "Please specify a valid phone number");

$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      phoneUS: true
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: what problem you are facing tell me..

Comment: Are you using any plugin for that??

Comment: I would say the best way to go about this is to strip out the white space before validating. That way you can just test for the numbers, and the minlength will also work. It also means if someone decides to put in a number with different formatting, it will still work. More usable, and easier to validate!

Comment: Trying to have validation for a textbox so that it only takes numbers with the format ### ### #### eg. 012 673 4498

Comment: Yes i'm using a plugin, but there is no method for phone numbers. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Options_for_the_validate.28.29_method

Comment: Sounds like a job for a [regular expression](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+regular+expression).

Comment: If you're trying to validate ### ### #### format I'd suggest you implement some sort of autocomplete that will insert spaces (or dashes/hyphens) in right places ie. ###-###-####.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneSA", function (phone_number, element) {
    phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, "");
    return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 && 
        phone_number.match(/^(0-?)?(\([0-9]\d{2}\)|[0-9]\d{2})-?[0-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/); //(0-?) = 0, ([0-9]\d{2}\) = 3 digits from 0-9 , d{4} 4 didgets, $ end of number
}, "Please specify a valid phone number");
```

Answer (score 1):

The [plugin author's page](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) has a link to an "additional validation methods" pack ([hotlink to source](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/additional-methods.js)) that includes a "phoneUS" validation rule. Simply drop that in and you 're good to go.

If you want to customize the acceptable patterns, that file also contains a "pattern" rule that allows you to validate by specifying a regular expression. In fact, that's how the "phoneUS" rule works as well: by testing the input for the expression

```
/^(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/
```

Comment: Jea i just found that, could you show me how to edit it to SA ### ### #### or just show me what a us number looks like and i will try it my self

Comment: Type out a US number please so i can make sense of all the numbers and \d in that line.

Comment: @Pomster: depends on what you want to do. Are spaces mandatory? Is another character such as `-` allowed instead of space? You have to specify all that. Also, the script I linked to has examples. Did you read them?

Comment: just spaces allowed. i'm pulling data of a database and then validating it afterwards. or validating before input to database

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script which I am using. Modify the code according to your needs. The id `errorContainer` is for showing your error message.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $().ready(function() {
    $("#frmMain").validate({
        errorLabelContainer:'#errorContainer',
        showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
            if(errorList.length)
            {
                $('#errorContainer').html(errorList[0]['message']);
            }
        },
            highlight:function(element,errorClass){
            $(element).parent('td').addClass('error');
            },
        unhighlight:function(element,errorClass){
                $(element).parent('td').removeClass('error');
        },
        rules: {
                        TelNumber: {
                required: true,
                number:true 
            }
                    },
            messages: {
                TelNumber: "Please enter a valid phone number",
            }
        });
   });
</script>
```

Before trying to implement this make sure your jQuery file is loading successfully and working properly.

I will suggest trying to use some UI for validation, that will be easy to implement.